# What is the value of this integral:

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-kx} dx$$
When the value of k is a positive real number, it is integrable. But what is the value of integral when k is complex, such as $k=2i$. Then what is the value of $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2ix} ~dx $$

Comment: I am pretty sure that for $k=2i$ the integral does not converge. Take the antiderivative and tell me: what is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp(-2ix)$?

Comment: You are right, this integtral does not concverge.

Comment: Use Euler's formula and you get an integral over a cosine and a sine with the same infinite limits.  This should give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $k\in\Bbb C$, we can easily notice that $$\int e^{-kx}dx=-\dfrac{e^{-kx}}{k}+C$$

Ignoring the $C$, we need to take the limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$ to find $\int_0^\infty e^{-kx}dx$:

$$\left[-\dfrac{e^{-kx}}{k}\right]_0^\infty=\lim_{x\to\infty}-\dfrac{e^{-kx}}{k}+\dfrac{e^{-k0}}{k}=\frac1k-\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{e^{-kx}}{k}$$

Because $k$ is complex we say $k=a+ib;a,b\in\Bbb R$ hence we left with $$\frac1k\left(1-\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-ax}e^{-ibx}\right)$$
Because $\exp(-ibx)$ is bounded(and periodic) we need to demand something from $a$, if $a=0$ we left with the limit of periodic function: does not converge. If $a<0$ we have $\exp(cx)$, the limit is $\infty$, and multiplying by the pariodic function(which 'change  symbols') does not converge. When $a>0$ we have $\exp(-ax)\to0$, periodic times $0$ goes to $0$, hence we left with $$\int_0^\infty e^{-kx}dx=\begin{cases}\frac1k&\Re\left(k\right)>0\\\mbox{Does not exists}&\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$