# Definite integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(1+i)t} \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: integration

Does this integral exist?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(1+i)t} \mathrm{d}t$$

Wolfram Alpha says it does not converge, but it's an excercise in a book (Signals and Systems) and I actually think it should converge to 0.

Comment: What's $x$ ? a number. real. complex

Comment: WA doesn't say that it diverges! http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E(-(1%2Bi)t)+dt+from+0+to+infty

Comment: I've got a feeling OP typed mixed up $x$ and $t$ in either the StackExchange question or a search in WolframAlpha. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E(-(1%2Bi)t)+dx+from+0+to+infty

Comment: Sorry, my bad! The x should actually be e (it's my first time using Latex). I'll edit the question.

Comment: Interestingly, after editing the link given by Jam, Wolfram alfa DOES say the integral converges. I must have been using it wrong.

Comment: Hint: use Euler's identitiy, $e^{a + b i} = e^a (\cos b + i \sin a)$

Comment: A nearly identical variant of this question was already asked and answered very recently. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878269/what-is-the-value-of-this-integral

Comment: I re-checked my math and I arrived at the same result as wolfram alpha. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2):

As the exponential is an holomorphic function which tends to zero for negative real parts,

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-(1+i)t}dt=-\left.\frac{e^{-(1+i)t}}{1+i}\right|_0^\infty=\frac1{1+i}.$$

This is perfectly confirmed by Alpha.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+i} = \frac{1 - i}{2}$, rationalizing denominators.